# Local pods with include folders flattened in derived data folder

Tags: xcode, cocoapods

I have multiple local pods that simply point to source files.  They're in folder structures to avoid naming collisions.  When I build, the include's seem to find the files in their expected folder structure, but the build pulls all headers into ~/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/[app]/Build/Products/[whatever]

All the files get copied to that folder directly, and if two different folders had a file with the same name, one gets blown away, and builds fail.

The podspec is super simple.

Pod::Spec.new do |s|

# ―――  Spec Metadata  ―――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――― #
  #
  #  These will help people to find your library, and whilst it
  #  can feel like a chore to fill in it's definitely to your advantage. The
  #  summary should be tweet-length, and the description more in depth.
  #

s.name         = "Gson"
  s.version      = "0.0.1"
  s.summary      = "A short description of Gson."

s.source_files  = "Gson/**/*.{h,m}"

s.public_header_files = "Gson/**/*.h"
  s.header_mappings_dir = "Gson"

end

Its a j2objc build, in case you're wondering what "Gson" is and why the folders thing is a big deal.

One of the included projects magically doesn't do this.  I'm experimenting with various setting combinations to try to figure it out, but so far nothing.

I've found virtually nothing directly related to this, and that along with the one magic pod that doesn't do this, makes me thing I'm doing something obviously not correct.

These files only show up when I actually run the build from xcode, not when installing the pods.  Just fyi.

The workaround has been renaming files with conflicts, but that's going to have to change at some point.

Thoughts?  Thanks in advance.